# Passing style resource id from XML to class not working

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a custom widget in a library project (Spinnerbutton) that I want to use in an application project. 
The custom widget contains a TextView and I want to pass a style to that TextView from my app project.

This is my attrs.xml (in the library project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="Spinnerbutton">
        <attr name="myTextAppearence" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

And the app's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.spinnerbuttonlib"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.Spinnerbutton
        android:id="@+id/sbp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        custom:myTextAppearence="@style/SmallTextGray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's how I try to read my custom attribute in the Spinnerbutton class:

```
public Spinnerbutton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.Spinnerbutton);

    int textStyleId = a.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.Spinnerbutton_myTextAppearence, -1);

    a.recycle();

}
```

textStyleId always return -1, so the value is not passed from my layout to the class.

What's wrong here?

Comment: In what package is your custom `Spinnerbutton` class? and in which package in your activity?

Comment: The SPinnerbutton class is in com.example.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton and the Activity is in com.example.myapp

Comment: looks all right. I tried it without library project works. I could use the spinner button in myproject. But i guess you need to customize the style by customizing the parent style.

Comment: Well I think the fact that the widget and the custom attribute are in a library is the problem ...

Comment: I think i found the answer. yes you should use the style in android library project as the parent style. Then customize the style in your project

Comment: check my post and let me know if it helps

Comment: instead of passing style resource id from XML to class not working you can customize the styles in your project  by using the styles in library project as parent. But why do you need to update in library project from android project?

Comment: Post the xml where you have declared this style "SmallTextGray"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library project has a Customview `Spinnerbutton` which extends TextView (in you case it may be different. For testing i extended TextView).

Now if i understand correctly this view is used in android project and you need to set the style to that custom view which can be done as below.

Use the style in android library project as the parent style and then customize the style in android project `styles.xml`. Now set the style to the customview.

```
package com.example.customviewattributes.p1;


import com.example.customviewattributes.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Spinnerbutton extends TextView{
    public Spinnerbutton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
    public Spinnerbutton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Spinnerbutton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // real work here
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.Spinnerbutton,
                0, 0
        );

        try {
            int textStyleId = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Spinnerbutton_myTextAppearence, -1);
            Log.i("................ID is",""+textStyleId);
            // to make sure i logged the id 
            this.setText("hello");
            this.setTextAppearance(context,textStyleId);
            // set the style to text
           } finally {
               // release the TypedArray so that it can be reused.
               a.recycle();
           }
    }
 }
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/QText</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
   <style name="QText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/ccolor</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="Spinnerbutton">
        <attr name="myTextAppearence" format="reference" />
 </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ccolor">#ff3232</color>

</resources>
```

All the above in library project.

Now in Another Android Project

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >

    <com.example.customviewattributes.p1.Spinnerbutton
        android:id="@+id/sbp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
com.example.customviewattributes.p1.Spinnerbutton cv = (Spinnerbutton) findViewById(R.id.sbp);
cv.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.QText1);
cv.setText("hello");
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/QText</item> 
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
   <style name="QText1" parent="@style/QText"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/ccolor</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ccolor">#4F47B7</color>

</resources>
```

Snap

This is for android project

[image]

Now if i run library project as a normal android project

Snap

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. The downside I guess of your approach is that in the main app project, I can only use styles that were predefined in the library project, right?

Comment: @Ascorbin yes. but i guess there is a solution for what you asked. I am also thinking of alternatives. But the above should work if you want to customize the appearance.

Comment: @Ascorbin you can customize the parent style.

Comment: @Ascorbin now in parent i din't define attribute text all caps. In android project styles i can have `<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>` Though library project  styles does not have i can customize the one in android project. All texts appears in caps. Is that what you meant in your first comment??

Comment: @Ascorbin also you can have other styles for other views in your activity in android project. So i am not sure i understand your first comment clearly

Comment: As to your textAllCaps example: did you successfully pass this style via XML or did you set it programmatically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43415/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ascorbin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put the xmlns:custom with your app package name, like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.yourapppackage"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.Spinnerbutton
        android:id="@+id/sbp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        custom:myTextAppearence="@style/SmallTextGray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you still have the problem, try to use the default xmlns namespace, like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.Spinnerbutton
        android:id="@+id/sbp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        custom:myTextAppearence="@style/SmallTextGray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this isn't working either :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have better luck if your custom XML namespace is:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this isn't working either :(

Answer (score 0):

change layout:

```
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.Spinnerbutton
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sbp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    custom:myTextAppearence="@style/SmallTextGray" />
```

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'myTextAppearence' in package 'android'

Answer (score 0):

try with this in attrs.xml
from

```
<attr name="myTextAppearence" format="reference" />
```

to this

```
<attr name="myTextAppearence" format="integer" />
```

and

```
 int textStyleId = a.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.Spinnerbutton_myTextAppearence, -1); in Spinnerbutton() constructor
```

> ```
> to
> ```

```
int textStyleId = a.getInt(
            R.styleable.Spinnerbutton_myTextAppearence, -1);
```

it will work